# How do I use Icalendar::HasComponents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar

Regarding https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/pull/132: Given that I have a

```
@cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
```

How do I use [Icalendar::HasComponents](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/master/lib/icalendar/has_components.rb) to add X-WR-CALNAME, X-PUBLISHED-TTL and X-WR-CALDESC properties to `@cal`?

I want to generate these extra properties in my .ics file so that I could add it  to Google Calendar and Outlook and allow them to specify

- X-WR-CALNAME  - calendar name
- X-PUBLISHED-TTL - refresh interval
- X-WR-CALDESC - calendar description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler than I thought:

```
cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
cal.append_custom_property("X-WR-CALNAME","My Calendar") 
cal.append_custom_property("X-PUBLISHED-TTL","PT1H")  # every hour
cal.append_custom_property("X-WR-CALDESC","My Desc")
```

Reference: https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/master/lib/icalendar/has_properties.rb